# How correctly format the dataset to train a llama2 alpaca fine tuned model?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, llama, alpaca

I would like to fine tunning a llama2-alpaca model called [bode](https://huggingface.co/recogna-nlp/bode-7b-alpaca-pt-br).

I have a web-scrapped [dataset of questions and answers](https://huggingface.co/datasets/celsowm/meu_site_juridico_perguntas_e_respostas) and I would like to use it on **SFTTrainer** to fine tunning that model to this specific domain but I don't know how correctly format the dataset to this model because on [hugging face documentation](https://huggingface.co/blog/llama2#how-to-prompt-llama-2) is something like this:

```
<s>[INST] <<SYS>>
{{ system_prompt }}
<</SYS>>

{{ user_message }} [/INST]
```

But on this very [model datacard](https://huggingface.co/recogna-nlp/bode-7b-alpaca-pt-br), they suggest something like:

```
Abaixo está uma instrução que descreve uma tarefa. Escreva uma resposta que complete adequadamente o pedido.

### Instrução:
{instruction}

### Resposta:"""
```

So, is there a method to get via API the prompt used? If so, what kind of modification do I need to do pass it to SFTTrainer?

Comment: This function [tokenizer.apply_chat_template](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/chat_templating) returns the prompted string from an array of chat messages. There is no guarantee that the `recogna-nlp/bode-7b-alpaca-pt-br` model properly overrides this function though. I'd recommend using what the model data card states as that is most likely what the model was finetuned and tested with.